# Java Streams Map Function with Private Inner Class Error

Tags: java, stream, map-function

**In short:**

I am trying to use a Java stream + map function to create a list of objects to return as response entities. But the compiler complains about private access for an inner class (despite not doing so in other circumstances).

**Code:**

```
public class Donkey {
...

   public DonkeyResponseEntity toResponseEntity() {
      DonkeyResponseEntity dre = new DonkeyResponseEntity();
      dre.id = this.id;
      dre.name = this.name;
      dre.numDonkeysInPossee = this.numDonkeysInPossee;

      return dre;
   }

   private class DonkeyResponseEntity {
      public Long id;
      public String name;
      public Integer numDonkeysInPossee;
   }
}

public class DonkeyService {
...
   public ResponseEntity<?> getDonkeys(List<Donkey> previousDonkeyList) {
   ...
      List<Object> donkeyPossee = previousDonkeyList.stream()
         .map(donkey -> donkey.toResponseEntity()).collect(Collectors.toList()); // !!ERROR HERE!!

      return new ResponseEntity<>(donkeyPossee, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
...
}
```

The error happens on the line with `.map(donkey -> donkey.toResponseEntity())`.

**Why I'm Confused:**

If I wrote something like the following, there is no access error:

```
Object d = previousDonkeyList.get(0).toResponseEntity();
```

or even

```
List<Object> donkeyPossee = previousDonkeyList.stream()
   .filter(donkey -> donkey.toResponseEntity() == null);
```

**Request:**

Can someone please explain why this happens? I'm not quite sure why `map` would take issue with this.

**Clarification:**

I'm not looking for alternative ways to accomplish this (using `forEach` and manually adding to a `List` works); I just want to know why `map` doesn't approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences here come from the fact that the `map` method in the `Stream` class actually uses the **type of the object** returned from the mapping function - in this case it's `DonkeyResponseEntity`. The `filter` method does not operate in any way on the actual type, only on the **object instance** (verifies if the reference points to `null` and **returns a boolean**). When getting the first element from the list you also do not refer to the **type**, because the reference is of type `Object`:

```java
// no error
Object d = previousDonkeyList.get(0).toResponseEntity();
```

If you were to use reference of type `DonkeyResponseEntity`, the compiler would mark it as an error as well:

```java
// error
DonkeyResponseEntity d = previousDonkeyList.get(0).toResponseEntity();
```

Interestingly if you used `var`, the compiler would not mark it as an error, because no explicit private type is used:

```java
// no error
var d = previousDonkeyList.get(0).toResponseEntity();
```

but even if the private class had public methods, you wouldn't be able to access them.

If you casted the returned object in the `map` method, the compiler would not mark it as an error, because it doesn't need to know ("see" - have access to) the actual type of the object:

```java
// no error
.map(donkey -> (Object) donkey.toResponseEntity())
```